# qwtknob set precision

Tags: c++, qt

In the default case qwtknob precision is two decimal places, I need to be accurate to three decimal places.

```
#include "knobtest.h"

knobtest::knobtest(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.Knob, SIGNAL(sliderMoved(double)), this, SLOT(knobChange(double)));
}

knobtest::~knobtest()
{

}

void knobtest::knobChange(double value)
{
    ui.lcdNumber->display(value);
}
```

[image]

how should I write the code?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should include your attempt with your question.

Comment: Please share, what you have tried so far....

Comment: @sebo1234 I have re-edited the question

Comment: I'm not a UI expert but my 2c -- on such a knob, with such a range, you don't want users to have to move their cursor half of a pixel on their screen to get that 0.05 on the display. I guess you either change the range of the knob to be e.g. between 0 and 0.1 (then you can worry about two decimals from a UX perspective), or you change your control to something else than a knob.